# Integration with parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate a function which has a parameter `u`.

Here is the code I have written

```
Integrate[((Sin[x] - Sinh[x] - 
     1.36222*(Cos[x] - 
        Cosh[x]))/(1 - (Sin[x] - Sinh[x] - 
         1.36222*(Cos[x] - Cosh[x]))*u)^2), {x, 0, 1}]
```

Its not working.

Is there any other way say numerically to solve this

(**Note that `u(t)` function of `t` and I am integrating with respect to `x`, so I don't have the information of its value, at the most I can say is its real**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using NIntegrate

```
f[u_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[((Sin[x] - Sinh[x] -1.36222*(Cos[x] -Cosh[x]))/(1- (Sin[x] - Sinh[x] -1.36222*(Cos[x] - Cosh[x]))*u)^2), {x, 0, 1}]
```

thereby parameter u is assumed to be const[x].

```
 Plot[f[u], {u, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to used this `f[u]` as an expression for ODE of `u` , so is there any way to have an explicit expression of `f[u]` ?

Comment: @T S Singh It is an explicit expression, which can be used in `NDSolve`.