# Integrate Differential Form with Parameter with DifferentialForms.m?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, differential-geometry

In [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181213/integration-with-parameters), it is shown how to integrate a function with parameter(s) and output a function of the parameter(s).

I am trying to do something similar with the [DifferentialForms.m package](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/482/). I have defined the Faraday 2-form and its potential 1-form

```
<< DifferentialForms`
g[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = t[x, x] + t[y, y] + t[z, z] - t[tau, tau] 
phi[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = 0
A[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = {0, 0, y}
Elec[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = -Grad[phi[x, y, z, tau], {x, y, z}] - 
  D[A[x, y, z, tau], {tau}]
B[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = Curl[A[x, y, z, tau], {x, y, z}]
F[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = 
 Elec[x, y, z, tau][[1]]*d[x, tau] + 
  Elec[x, y, z, tau][[2]]*d[y, tau] + 
  Elec[x, y, z, tau][[3]]*d[z, tau] + B[x, y, z, tau][[1]]*d[y, z] + 
  B[x, y, z, tau][[2]]*d[z, x] + B[x, y, z, tau][[3]]*d[x, y]
A4Jeff1[x_, y_, z_, tau_] = 
 Simplify[HomotopyOperator[F[x, y, z, tau]]]
```

Now, I define a loop with a time parameter, to evaluate the time-varying magnetic flux for a DC motor:

```
ChainJeff = 
 Chain[{x -> r* Sin[q]*Cos[th], y -> r*Cos[q]*Cos[th], 
   z -> r*Sin[th], tau -> q}, {r, 0, 1} , {th, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

This integral does not work

```
Phi1[q_?NumericQ] = Integral[F[x, y, z, tau], ChainJeff]
```

but this integral does

```
Phi2[q_] = Integral[A4Jeff1[x, y, z, tau], Boundary[ChainJeff]]
```

Note that I would then like to differentiate both with respect to time

```
BackEMF1[q_] = D[Phi1[q], {q}]
BackEMF2[q_] = D[Phi2[q], {q}]
```

to simulate the back-EMF for the DC motor. Is there something similar to `NIntegrate` I can call or write for `DifferentialForm.m` to get my construction to work? Note that if I take out the parameter `q` and just plug in `q=0`, the first integral works. Here are links to notebooks: http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/FaradaySurfaceIntegral01.nb http://deadbeatjeff.sdf.org/Scripts/FaradaySurfaceIntegral02.nb

Comment: It might be better to send these questions directly to the author of that package (if he is still active in the field).

Comment: I have contacted the author of the package directly.